# Using Cauchy's Residue Theorem, I miss a term. Why?

Tags: complex-analysis

In calculating with the residue theorem I find
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-z^2}}{1+z^2} \, dx = \pi e$$

Online, a video calculating this integrand by means of "Feynman's trick"  produces another term, $-\pi \cdot e\cdot \mathrm{erf}(1)$. I find only one term from the Residue at $(0,i)$ in the upper half-plane.  The limit of the integral on the semicircular arc, I find goes $0$ as the radius goes to infinity.  Have I neglected something?

Comment: Why does the integral over the semicircle go to zero? For example if we fix the real part of $z$ then $e^{-z^2}/(1+z^2)$ is unbounded as $\operatorname{im} z\to+\infty$.

Comment: Because I am a dummy! :)